# How to display string as correctly formatted html output in Jupyter notebook using R?

Tags: html, r, regex, jupyter-notebook, output

Running the `chatgpt::ask_chatgpt()` inside a Jupyter notebook (in VS Code) will return unformatted text with some special characters that I presume is supposed to denote formatting.

Example:

````
ans <- ask_chatgpt("Can you provide a print 'Hello world!' code snippet in R, with a brief explanation of that the function does?")

*** ChatGPT input:

Can you provide a print 'Hello world!' code snippet in R, with a brief explanation of that the function does?

ans


'Certainly! Here\'s a code snippet to print \'Hello world!\' in R:\n\n```R\nprint("Hello world!")\n```\n\nExplanation:\n1. The `print()` function in R is used to display messages or values.\n2. In this case, the string "Hello world!" is passed as an argument to the `print()` function.\n3. When this code is executed, it will print the message "Hello world!" to the console.\n\nThe `print()` function is a versatile function in R that can be used to display strings, numbers, variables, or any other object. It converts the given object into a readable format and prints it to the console. In this particular case, it simply prints the string "Hello world!" to produce the desired output.'
````

The Jupyter notebooks cell output is set to 'HTML', and I want the text formatted accordingly. Presumably, `\n` denotes line break, and `\n1` and ```` ``` ```` denotes list element and code block, respectively. I tried substituting "\n" with the HTML line break tag (`<br>`), but the output remains unformatted, with just the "\n" replaced with "
".

Example:

````
gsub("*\\\n( |\\\n)", "<br>", ans)

</> 
'Certainly! Here\'s a code snippet to print \'Hello world!\' in R:<br>```R\nprint("Hello world!")\n```<br>Explanation:\n1. The `print()` function in R is used to display messages or values.\n2. In this case, the string "Hello world!" is passed as an argument to the `print()` function.\n3. When this code is executed, it will print the message "Hello world!" to the console.<br>The `print()` function is a versatile function in R that can be used to display strings, numbers, variables, or any other object. It converts the given object into a readable format and prints it to the console. In this particular case, it simply prints the string "Hello world!" to produce the desired output.'
````

I'm trying to understand why it does not recognise the `<br>` tag and format the text correctly, and how to create correctly formatted output in either HTML or Markdown (or both) in a Jupyter notebook (in VS Code).

How the output ought to be formatted (and what I want):

> 'Certainly! Here\'s a code snippet to print \'Hello world!\' in R:
>
> ```
> print("Hello world!")
> ```
>
> Explanation:
>
> 1. The `print()` function in R is used to display messages or values.
> 2. In this case, the string "Hello world!" is passed as an argument to the `print()` function.
> 3. When this code is executed, it will print the message "Hello world!" to the console.
>
> The `print()` function is a versatile function in R that can be used to display strings, numbers, variables, or any other object. It converts the given object into a readable format and prints it to the console. In this particular case, it simply prints the string "Hello world!" to produce the desired output.'

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, simply changing ouput in the cells "More Actions..."-menu (<kbd>…</kbd>) does not change the rendering of the text correctly. However, the output can be rendered correctly using the `IRdisplay::display_<text>()` functions. The IRdisplay::display_html() will recognise the `<br>`-tags in the example above. However, transforming the tags in the original text (`/n`, `/n1` and ```` ``` ````) is unnecessary, as they will be correctly recognised by as Markdown tags by the `IRdisplay::display_markdown()` function.

Example:

```
library(chatgpt)
library(magrittr)

ask_chatgpt("Can you provide a print 'Hello world!' code snippet in R, with a brief explanation of that the function does?") %>%
IRdisplay::display_markdown()
```

[image]

This solves my current predicament, however, it does not answer why changing rendering in the cells "More Actions..." menu to Markdown did not produce the desired outcome.